# Web-based newsletter interface without password

Tags: web-apps, email, self-hosted, newsletter

I need to send newsletters to around 10.000 (elderly) users and need an interface for users to subscribe/unsubscribe that needs to be as user friendly as possible.

Requirements:

- no external service
- should work without the need for a password
- double opt-in (user clicks on "subscribe" and gets a confirmation email with a link)
- export of all mail adresses should be possible

Open Source would be nice.

The second point is the reason I cannot use GNU Mailman.